# Return DataTable using async .net 4.0

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, async-await

I have a method that returns a datatable. I thought using .net 4.0 I could just async logic and return data. But this code returns null Datatable object. Any ideas what is wrong with this code.

```
public DataTable GetData(string sql, string connectionName)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)GetDataAsync(sql, connectionName).AsyncState;
    return dt;
}

private async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(string sql, string connectionName)
{
    return await TaskEx.Run(() => { return FillData(sql, connectionName); });
}

private DataTable FillData(string sql, string connectionName)
{
    SqlConnection conn = _connections.Where(w => w.ConnectionName == connectionName).Single().Connection;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adp.Fill(ds);

    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: You can't use `async` / `await` with .NET 4.0 or C# 4. It's a new feature in C# 5, and depends on types in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Jon - since he's using TaskEx.Run, I'm guessing he's using the async targeting pack, which lets you target 4.0 and use async/await

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you can't use `async` / `await` with .NET 4 or C# 4. It's a new feature in C# 5. There were CTPs which installed on top of .NET 4, but there are definite bugs in those CTPs - *don't* use them. You should use the full release version of .NET 4.5, which includes the C# 5 compiler. (All this is in Visual Studio 2012.)

Secondly, you're using the wrong property of the task, as Cuong Le showed. The [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) property is how you get at the result of a `Task<T>`.

Thirdly, after making the change to use the `Result` property, you'd be blocking for the table to be fetched - making it pointless. This:

```
public DataTable GetData(string sql, string connectionName)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)GetDataAsync(sql, connectionName).Result;
    return dt;
}
```

... is largely equivalent to:

```
public DataTable GetData(string sql, string connectionName)
{
    return FillData(sql, connectionName);
}
```

If you're going to start a task and immediately wait on it, you might as well just call the method synchronously.

Comment: Ok so how do i do this in .net 3.5 if can help with that Jon??

Comment: I was only going to use 4.0 for async so i wont use it now.

Comment: @Malcolm: Any reason you don't want to use 4.5?

Comment: I thought you said it was 5.0 only. Yes I could use 4.5.

Comment: @Malcolm: I said it was in C# 5.0, which is what you use with .NET 4.5.

Comment: Can i do that in VS2010 express?

Comment: @Malcolm: No, you need Visual Studio 2012. There are some Express editions of VS2012 out now, and the "general" C# one (non-Win8, non-web) will be available some time after Win8 launches.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17167/discussion-between-malcolm-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Malcolm: Sorry, I can't do chat at the moment, as I'm about to get off a train and walk. I think I've laid out all the options to you anyway though...

Answer (score 8):

My own source code.

```
public static async Task<DataTable> GetDataTableAsync(this System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string tableName = null)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<DataTable> source = new TaskCompletionSource<DataTable>();
        var resultTable = new DataTable(tableName ?? command.CommandText);
        DbDataReader dataReader = null;

        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == true)
        {
            source.SetCanceled();

            await source.Task;
        }

        try
        {
            await command.Connection.OpenAsync();
            dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.Default);
            resultTable.Load(dataReader);
            source.SetResult(resultTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            source.SetException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataReader != null)
                dataReader.Close();

            command.Connection.Close();
        }

        return resultTable;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, however you should also pass your cancellation token to the OpenAsync and ExecuteReaderAsync methods so that cancels will stop these also

Comment: Thank you for actually providing a solution. Where do you get the cancellation token to pass in?

Comment: You can use the `using` pattern to close everything for you on dispose.

Comment: Here only the creation of the reader is executed asynchronously. Meanwhile, data loading is done synchronously: `resultTable.Load(dataReader);` And this is a time-consuming operation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `async` code, then [don't block on it](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Also, make sure you're using the [Async Targeting Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576) and not an Async CTP.

```
private async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(string sql, string connectionName)
{
  return await TaskEx.Run(() => { return FillData(sql, connectionName); });
}

private async GetAndProcessDataAsync()
{
  DataTable table = await GetDataAsync("my sql", "my connection name");
  ProcessData(table);
}
```