# Cancel background worker that is doing intensive opetation

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a winform with 2 grids and I have a background worker that I'm using to retrieve large amounts of data from our database.
The background worker launches when the user changes row from the left grid (it takes the row as parameter for the SQL procedure) and once it finishes, the datatable is merged with the binding source of the right grid and the information is shown.

Here is my code:

```
// Called when left grid focused row changes
public void LaunchTransactionWorker(int rowId)
{
    if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(rowId);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = tableAdapterLog.GetData((int)e.Argument);
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataTable = (ds.DataTableTransactionsLog)e.Result;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        ds.DataTableLog.Clear();
        ds.DataTableLog.Merge(dataTable);
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `DoWork` function only does a single thing. From my understanding (I'm probably wrong), the background worker launches a new thread that does the `DoWork` function. There I could look if the cancellation flag was raised and stop it. But how can I stop it, if it will be busy in the `Fill` ? If I add a check `if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending) e.Cancel = true;` , it will never reach no ?

Comment: To get this out of the way: There is no way you could switch to Task/Async, right?

Comment: I did not think of replacing the background worker. It is vastly used in the project I'm working on, so I wanted to keep it for that reason, but I think it could be a good idea. My question does still stand, I would like to know if there is a way to cancel that operation with a background worker

Comment: Well, basically, using `bgw.IsCancellationPending` makes only sense, if you have a (or several) loop or loops in which you could check that marker. If you only have one single operation, you'd need to pass on the signal so the called function's logic can check if it needs to abort prematurely. Maybe I am missing something, though ...

Comment: exactly, but that is the issue, how can I cancel it if it's stuck in the single operation. I could start it in a separate thread and kill it if the row change event triggers and one operation is currently happning

Comment: @Fildor Im trying to change it to Task/Async, but I'm not aware on how to use the `CancellationTokenSource`. I would be interested in your approach

Comment: If you gonna stick with the BGW, then try [Cancelling ADO.NET DataAdapter.Fill Method On The Fly By Throwing An Error](https://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/cancelling-dataadapter-fill-method-on-the-fly-by-throwing-an-error/) and [Fill DataGridView and cancel process using DataAdapter and BackgroundWorker](https://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/fill-datagridview-and-cancel-process-using-dataadapter-and-backgroundworker/).

Comment: oh ok, I see. For sure, throwing an error will work, thanks for that input. I would however prefer a more standard approach, if any.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595119/return-datatable-using-async-net-4-0/24399507